# Setting Default Printing Options For A Sharepoint 2010 List Item

Tags: sharepoint-server, printing, settings, default

I need to change our printer default settings to print out list item (edit form). Can this be done from within SharePoint 2010?

If we right click in the edit form and select print the result is too small to read. if we use "print preview" we can change the "Change Print Size" from "Shrink to fit" to 100%. Unfortunately this causes the printing options to change and we then need to go to print-options and reset it to "Only the selected frame"

I realize this may not be a "SharePoint 2010 question" but I have no-one but ya'll to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change printer default settings in the SharePoint 2010.

You should change printer default settings in the explorer printer settings.